# How to use processing.py in google colaboratory

Tags: python-3.x, processing, google-colaboratory

Recently I've been studying a lot on the processing library (mainly using p5.js) and was delighted to find out that in the processing IDE, there is a python mode, processing.py.

I want to try using it in google colaboratory. I tried using pip install to install it in colab and in the console it said it was installed successfully but when I try running a script that usually runs in the python mode of the processing IDE, it doesn't work. Below is a screen cap of the code and the error. In the processing IDE, (without the last 2 lines), this will show a 400 x 400 gray canvas with a circle drawn at its center.

[image]

I also tried installing java into the colab just in case processing.py requires java. Nothing seems to work though. For those who want to see the entire notebook, here is the link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19UVAR2iOWk4NnrHxNhd_XL03MUoKrCF3?usp=sharing It is set so that anyone with the link can open it.

I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is not possible to use https://py.processing.org on Colab, as it is based on the Jython interpreter, a Python 2 that runs on the Java Virtual Machine (the upside of Jython being that we can use most of the librairies created by the Processing Java community, available with a few clicks from the IDE).

You might be able to run this new experimental "Processing in Python 3" project on Colab: https://github.com/p5py/p5

Answer (score 0):

There is a [new p5 library in pyPI](https://p5.readthedocs.io/en/latest) that can be installed:

```py
!pip install -U p5
import p5
```

However, I have had problems getting the chart to show. I believe that the problem is getting Colab to write to my display. It would be great if someone could solve this...

Comment: oh but is it going to work in a locally hosted python environment such as a local jupyter notebook?

Comment: Isn’t the point of Google Colab that you are working in the Cloud, using Google’s servers and processors? If you want to do it locally, you can just run it locally (pip install p5). Am I missing your point?

Comment: Oh I was just wondering if the reason why its difficult to make it work in Colab is because of the notebook environment.

Comment: (sorry for the delayed response). No, I don't think it is due to the notebook environment. Or at least, that is not the main problem (apparently).